# I want to make a more details button/tab using JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make a kind of catalog and once someone presses the "show more" button it should show the description from the corresponding data I got from a API/JSON file. I tried using e.target but I'm stuck at this point.

```
function getCocktailItemsSuccessHandler(data) {
    for(item of data){

    const cardDiv = document.createElement("div")
    cardDiv.classList.add("card")
    cocktailGallery.appendChild(cardDiv)

    const nameCocktail = document.createElement("h2")
    nameCocktail.classList.add("listName")
    nameCocktail.innerText = item.name
    cardDiv.appendChild(nameCocktail)

    const img = document.createElement("img")
    img.src = item.image
    cardDiv.appendChild(img)

    const detailsButton = document.createElement("button")
    detailsButton.classList.add("detailsButton")
    detailsButton.innerHTML = 'More'
    detailsButton.addEventListener('click', detailsClickHandler)
    cardDiv.appendChild(detailsButton)

    }
}
function detailsClickHandler(e) {
    let details = e.target
    detailsContainer.innerHTML =  item.
}
```

Comment: Did any of these answers help solve your question? If so, please accept one as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your structure, you can store the incoming data in a variable that you can reference after the fact. See the lines with the `// <--- add this line` and then the whole `detailsClickHandler` function.

Another option of course is to create a `div` and insert the description text in it, hide it with `display:none` and toggle it on with the button click. The way I've presented below is more dynamic, but not neccesarily better.

```js
let theData = [] // <-- add this line
function getCocktailItemsSuccessHandler(data) {
  theData = data; // <-- add this line
  for (item of data) {
    const cardDiv = document.createElement("div")
    cardDiv.classList.add("card")
    cardDiv.setAttribute('data-id', item.id); // <-- add this line
    cocktailGallery.appendChild(cardDiv)

    const nameCocktail = document.createElement("h2")
    nameCocktail.classList.add("listName")
    nameCocktail.innerText = item.name
    cardDiv.appendChild(nameCocktail)

    const img = document.createElement("img")
    img.src = item.image
    cardDiv.appendChild(img)

    const detailsButton = document.createElement("button")
    detailsButton.classList.add("detailsButton")
    detailsButton.innerHTML = 'More'
    detailsButton.addEventListener('click', detailsClickHandler)
    cardDiv.appendChild(detailsButton)

  }
}

function detailsClickHandler(e) {
  let details = e.target
  // get the relative id
  let id = details.closest('.card').dataset.id;
  // get the item from the object
  let item = theData.filter(item => item.id.toString().trim() === id.toString().trim());
  detailsContainer.innerHTML = item[0].description; // or whatever field the html is in
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much restarted this little project and I get this error message: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
    at HTMLButtonElement.detailClickHandler (main.js:92:24)

is there a alternative to filter?

Comment: Actually that error is telling you that it cannot find the variable `theData` (trying to access the property `filter` of `undefined`). Did you add that top line to your code? `let theData = [] // <-- add this line`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the item dynamically to the detailsClickHandler() function and then use it there to update details.

```
detailsButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => detailsClickHandler(event, item))

function detailsClickHandler(event, item) {
    detailsContainer.innerHTML =  item
}
```

Comment: If you need to keep event, use this as event handler instead `(event) => detailsClickHandler(event, item)`. Your `detailsClickHandler()` method should accept both arguments